# MongoDB and the PHP driver

Tags: php, mongodb

There is a command line syntax in mongo that goes something like this

```
db.collection.find('nested_array.some_nested_key':'some_nested_value',{'nested_array.$' => 1})
```

This finds and returns just the "nested_array(s)" that match the criteria and not the entire object.

Problem is I can't seem to find the ".$" equivalent in the php driver. anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods in the MongoDB PHP driver are similar to their mongo shell counterparts, so the projection with the **[`$ positional`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)** operator also uses associative arrays to map **[fields](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php)** to MongoDB queries. Something like this will produce the desired result:

```
<?php
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->selectDB("test");
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, "collection_name");

    // search for nested array
    $fruitQuery = array("nested_array.some_nested_key" => "some_nested_value");

    // projection (fields to include)
    $projection =  array("_id" => false, "nested_array.$" => true);

    $cursor = $collection->find($query, $projection);
    foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
        var_dump($doc);
    }
?>
```